# Custom palette in embedded node-red not imported

Tags: express, node-red

I need to embed Node-red in express, I've used this [guide](https://nodered.org/docs/embedding.html) and it works.

Unfortunately, I can't import custom nodes. I try to import all dependencies in "package.json" of express as suggested in the guide, but it doesn't works.

If I start only node-red I can find the nodes in the palette.

Comment: It's not totally clear what your problem is from the question as it stands, can you add some more detail and maybe include the outline of the code you are using. Also any errors (e.g. in the browser console)

Comment: Solved
in this [link] (https://nodered.org/docs/configuration) guide,
I found that I have to declare nodesDir in configuration

Comment: If you have an answer please update the question with more details of the errors your saw and then add a proper answer and mark it as accepted to help others in the future.